# Is it grammatically correct to use 'Certification training' in this context?

Tags: grammar

This paragraph is for CV and I have a question. Is it grammatically correct to use 'Certification training'?

> 1. Certification
>
>    - Fluke Networks
>
>      - **Certification training** on the operation of the Network Analyser
>          Fluke Networks Etherscope®
>    - Cisco Network Academy
>
>      - CCNA Exploration: Accessing the WAN
>      - CCNA Exploration: LAN Switching and Wireless
>      - CCNA Exploration: Routing Protocols and Concept
>      - CCNA Exploration: Network Fundamentals

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: I probably would order the scope description as:  "... of the Fluke Networks Etherscope® network analyzer."   Also, by saying that you received certification training I might conclude that while you received the training you did not actually  receive your certification.  IF you did receive certification, then just say, "Fluke Networks certified in the operation of the Etherscope® network analyzer"  Or because of the way your bulleted list is constructed: simply 1. Certification.  o Fluke Networks  o Etherscope network analyzer operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can be more concise in this section.

You use "Certification" twice. All of these courses are certification, are they not?

So saying "Certification training" seems redundant to me. The repetition of "CCNA Exploration" is unnecessary as well.

I doubt you took these courses all at the same time. I would include the month and year of the course or just the year. This shows a progression of training with the company.

Something like this:

**1. Certification**

- Fluke Networks

  - Operation of the Network Analyzer Fluke Networks Etherscope® , *month/year*
- Cisco Network Academy, CCNA Exploration

  - Accessing the WAN, *month/year*
  - LAN Switching and Wireless, *month/year*
  - Routing Protocols and Concept, *month/year*
  - Network Fundamentals, *month/year*

this is basically how I would organize the section. Depending on how extensive your CV is you might add a bit more to the description of the certification of a specific course if there was anything special to talk about.

You should never have more than 2 pages with the most important information on the first page. The first page gets 100% attention. The second page only will be read 50% of the time and only if they are interested after the first page. Each succeeding page progressively gets 50% less attention.

Good Luck...

Answer (score 1):

The rules of grammar are sometimes different, when dealing with a Curriculum Vitae, than they are when writing a formal paper or essay (e.g. what is above is a  bulleted list, not a paragraph).  But in most cases, if you have a complete setence, you can use the same grammatical rules you normally would. In your example, *Certification training* is perfectly fine the way you have it. However, you should use the preposition *in* instead of *on* afterwards.

Google Books agrees:

["certification training in" (10,800 results)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&tbm=bks&q=%22certification%20training%20in%22)

vs

["certification training on" (30 results)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&tbm=bks&q=%22certification%20training%20in%22&oq=%22certification%20training%20in%22&gs_l=serp.3...15344.15748.0.15818.2.2.0.0.0.0.66.131.2.2.0.msedr...0...1.1.64.serp..2.0.0.BTH7k_LNKws)